# PhpStorm and Blade - Unresolved function or method

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-blade

PhpStorm says the call to foo() in the second set of script tags is to a unresolved function or method:

```
<script>
    function foo() {}
</script

<script>
    foo();
</script>
```

Therefore, I cannot use "Go To Implementation" because it can't find the function implementation in the first script tags.

How can I get PhpStorm to recognize the function implementation from other script tags?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to answer that question, however, I'm curious why you are you deciding to split your scripts between several tags?

Comment: This is just a simplified example to demonstrate the issue. In practice, the scripts are in separate files that are pulled together for each page. Since they are in different files, there are many `<script></script>` tags

Answer (score 3):

Known issue, please vote for [WEB-41572](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41572) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: Thanks lena, I voted and created another issue in the PhpStorm issue. Can't hurt for them to see it again in a different scenario.